# MPMoviePlayerViewController has no seek bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, streaming

My MPMoviePlayerViewController does not enable the seek bar nor the fast forward button. It only shows --:--, as it does when you stream. My code looks like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://REMOVED/listen.php?id=%@&token=%@", curid, token]]];
[[player moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];
[[player moviePlayer] setAllowsAirPlay:true];
[[player moviePlayer] ];
[[player moviePlayer] setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

and the file header looks like this:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4012742
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Date:Fri, 01 Mar 2013 17:28:57 GMT
Server:nginx admin
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.12
```

Why isn't it enabling the seek bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.
It was the "Content-range" header in php, which was missing and caused the seek to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[[player moviePlayer] setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
```

Comment: Removed the bar completely.

Comment: Can you just use a MPMoviePlayerController and add its subview?

Comment: The problem is not the MPMoviePlayerController itself, since the bar is being shown. But MP doesn't know how to seek.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Have you tried a different media link? Maybe a direct link an MP3 file or something? Also maybe try just initializing it and presenting it right way, don't play with anything else like AirPlay or RepeatMode.